# Can't login with new theme in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal

I'm facing some trouble and hope someone can help me. 
When I create a new custom theme, I can access the login page normally but just can't login.
I don't know why but the form is just not submitted when I press the login button. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on login page inspect it (F12 key usually), go to network tab and press login button. If no request is made it means that form is not submitted properly. Can be that you have some html element over submit button or some event handler is picking up click or submit events.

If there is a request inspect it for the values. If everything is ok then problems is most likely somewhere else, not in your theme.